# How to pass props to children class components in react router v6 without using <Outlet />?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-dom

I've been migrating React Router from v3 to v6 in a project and things got messy since I have some React function components and some React class component which I want to keep them as classes for performance reasons. I would like to inform that my project is built with React Redux. I have migrated the routes and it has been working very well. With the last version of routing in my app component which I use selectors with `mapStateToProps` and this way I am able to make those props available to all the children as you can see below.

```js
const childrenWrapper = React.Children.map(props.children, child => {
  return React.cloneElement(child, {
    currentOrganization: currentOrganization,
    organizationSlug: organizationSlug,
    eventSlug: eventSlug,
    isPreview: isPreview,
    user: user,
  });
});

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  user: selectUser(),
  currentOrganization: selectCurrentOrganization(),
  isLoaded: selectLoaded(),
  organizationCount: selectOrganizationCount()
});
```

This was working like a charm but with the router v6 I am only able to use `<Outlet />` to render the children and if I want to pass data to children I use it by defining props like `<Outlet context={{ currentOrganization: currentOrganization }}` and in the component if want to use this I simply use `useOutletContext` and get the data passed through `<Outlet />`. If everything was a function component I wouldn't need to ask this here since it is quite straight forward. I am wondering how can I tackle this problem of passing props to children with class components without using `Outlet` (anyway it is not working in the class components). I tried to do it with context api but by creating a separate component to and wrap the `<Outlet />` with that `context.provider` but children still didn't get any of those props defined in `AppContext`. So my question is how could I pass the props to the class components while using router v6. I changed my App.js component to function component already therefore I am able to use React Router v6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, your question isn't about passing props to a routed component, e.g. `<Route path="..." element={<SomeComponent thisIsAPassedProp={....} />} />` but rather you are using a layout route and passing a context value down via an `Outlet` and need to access that value from a React class-based component.

A trivial solution would be to create a custom Higher Order Component that ***can*** use the `useOutletContext` hook and pass the value as props.

Example:

```
import { useOutletContext } from 'react-router-dom';

export const withOutletContext = Component => props => {
  const contextValue = useOutletContext();

  return (
    <Component
      {...props}                  // <-- all other passed props
      contextValue={contextValue} // <-- the context value
    />
  );
};
```

Decorate the exported React class components that should be able to access this context value.

```
import { Component } from 'react';
import { compose } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withOutletContext } from '../path/to/withOutletContext';

class MyComponent extends Component {
  ...

  someFunction = () => {
    const { contextValue } = this.props;
    console.log(contextValue.currentOrganization);
    ...
  };

  ...
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  ...
});

export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps),
  withOutletContext,
)(MyComponent);
```

Now the decorated components will be able to access their nearest `Outlet`'s provided context value.

```
<Routes>
  ...
  <Route element={<LayoutRoute />}> {/* Provides Outlet context value */}
    ...
    <Route path="..." element={<MyComponent />} /> {/* Receives Outlet context value as props */}
    ...
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

Comment: works very good thanks i also have thought about creating a hoc and wrap the comoonents around with it but on the other hand i've been looking for a solution where i just do changes on the top level of the app and that reflects to everywhere. this way i won't have to change it each component by wrapping with this because project is pretty big. do u have some other idea how could be done or is it even possible to do it? if there is a package that could solve the issue that would also work.

Comment: @emira I don't believe you can avoid this issue. For all intents and purposes, React class components were effectively deprecated when React hooks were released. The React world has moved on to hooks. Sooner or later your app will need to catch up. This HOC allows your class components to remain relevant a while longer.